# How to achieve reversed document ordered XmlDataSource in ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, xmldatasource

I'm using an `asp:XmlDataSource` to list an xml document. It looks like this:

`<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Xml/History.xml" />`

And I'm using it in a `asp:Listview` like this:

`<asp:ListView runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" >`

I was wondering if there was a way to reverse the order, because **I would like the *last* row of the xml to be the *first* row in my list**. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your xml looked like this (for example):

```
<myxml>
  <row id="1">
  <row id="2">
</myxml>
```

then you can do an inline transform with something like this:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Xml/History.xml">
  <Transform>   
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="*">
     <myxml> 
        <xsl:for-each select="//row"> 
          <xsl:sort select="@id" order="descending" /> 
          <xsl:copy-of select="row"/> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
     </myxml>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</Transform>
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Looks cool, but I get a *'xsl' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.* exception. Any ideas?

Comment: can you update your answer to look like this?

`<Transform>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*">
   <myxml>
    <xsl:for-each select="//row">
     <xsl:sort select="@id" order="descending" />
     <xsl:copy-of select="row"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </myxml>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
</Transform>`

When you change it, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry, meant to mention that the full xslt was needed.  Updated accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just populate a list, reverse it, then bind to that list.

EDIT: It's hard to give an example, because it'll totally depend on your XML file, but the basic idea is below, where you'd change the select statement as required and maybe add some from statements as required.

```
XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(XMLFileName);
ListView.DataSource = (from XMLNode in XDoc.Nodes()
                       select XMLNode.ToString()).ToList().Reverse();
ListView.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for the example. Looks good. The implementation of Nathan seems easier, but thanks for your code!